# Powershell substring of a resultset

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a string in powershell which is having below data ,

```
     $job = "diagnosticCode":223412290,
            "severity":"Error",
            "component":"JobManager_User",
            "source":"User",
            "errorId":"VertexFailedFast",
            "message":"Vertex failed with a fail-fast error",
            "description":"Vertex failure triggered quick job abort". 
            "resolution":"",
            "helpLink":""
```

Here i wanted to catch "message" and give it to exception in Catch case, tried with $job[3].ToSTring() but could not work out.
Any help please.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Could you try and reword it? or show another example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a string, it looks more like a hash table desperate for some help.

To create a hash table you can do it this way:

```
$job = @{ diagnosticCode=223412290
        severity="Error"
        component="JobManager_User"
        source="User"
        errorId="VertexFailedFast"
        message="Vertex failed with a fail-fast error"
        description="Vertex failure triggered quick job abort"
        resolution=""
        helpLink="" }
```

Then you can access the message like this:

```
$job.message
```

It's unclear, however, how you got that "string", if it was passed to you as is, or if you built it.

Comment: "*It's unclear, however, how you got that "string"*" - my money is on it being a JSON string, with the `{}` missing. (and the description having a full stop instead of a comma outside the quotes).